# JMeter Password Encryption

Tags: jmeter, password-encryption

I need to pass this encrypted value in JMeter & every time there will be a similar kind of unique encryption passing.
yS0TNeqqu9py3NogSvUN6JJMC0on34ezkU2BQkpSR59gMelrTL+B1kds0ggNjmPvBNBJ6QCz94aG0B1pu1qyLslClzsyZUP2j1OXX3vTka+s6iTIE7Kp3bkF3oMwMX+dXSQx7AmQYc90h6v3DMEDa1uM0w/aun5Ap9uoPHGHh8FniHvvpC6w6xYKDptQ2xc+MlcYZLWNBqSFY0hWwnsVSpcRqu11q3RaxR4l9QcO/vDjRwVJYREBPCGe1Ep4vRt5Rl//+nHZ1IzRRSXcVmwkUo1Mfoirw5YvxbhoGGntiVqKUsDiipVMKxZYZBGLJWGQcAtIAQkv33VJPwgz0gba+Q==

I tried with ${__base64Encode()} but its not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine encryption algorithm like [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) which is being used for encoding and implement the same using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

You can inspect your page JavaScript code and look for the function which performs the password encryption, you should be able to guess the algorithm and its parameters from there.

More information: [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy)

Comment: Can I connect with you & resolve the Issue?

Comment: If the value is part of response you can correlate using post processor of your choice and pass in subsequent requests.